# Post Form won't call Servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, web.xml

So i have a post form which calls a Servlet to perform a search but the problem is that when i push the submit button it's completely unresponsive. Although when used in the same form in a different .jsp page it works as it should. If it had something to do with the servlet mapping there would be an error page from the tomcat server but i do not get such an error page. It's just completely unresponsive.

My HTML form:

```
   <form action="AnonSearchServlet" class="form-inline" method="post">
      <input type="search" name="location" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Destination, City, Address" required>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="When" name="daterange" value="" required/>
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input style="width: 20%; height: 46px" type="number" min="1" name="accomodates" class="form-control" placeholder="Guests" required>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Search</button>
    </form>
```

My Servlet:

```
public class AnonSearchServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String start_date;
        String end_date;
        String date_range = request.getParameter("daterange");
        UserBean user = new UserBean();
        String[] tokens = date_range.split(" ");
        start_date = tokens[0];
        end_date = tokens[2];

        try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            user.setUserID(0);
            System.out.println(user.getUserID());

            ResultSet search_rs = null;
            SearchBean search_bean = new SearchBean();

            search_bean.setUserId(user.getUserID());
            search_bean.setLocation(request.getParameter("location"));
            System.out.println(request.getParameter("location"));
            search_bean.setStreet(request.getParameter("location"));
            search_bean.setNeighbourhood(request.getParameter("location"));
            search_bean.setAccomodates(request.getParameter("accomodates"));
            search_bean.setStartDate(start_date);
            search_bean.setEndDate(end_date);

            search_bean = SearchDAO.search(search_bean);
            session.setAttribute("current_search", search_bean);
            response.sendRedirect("searchResults.jsp");


        } catch (Throwable thException) {
            System.out.println(thException);
        }
    }
}
```

And my web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AnonSearchServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Servlets.AnonSearchServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AnonSearchServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/AnonSearchServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: what is the URL when you try post it from the jsp page?

Comment: Did you check any error's in console?

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte It's from my index.jsp page (localhost:8080/index.jsp)

Comment: @VinothKrishnan there are not errors in console. After i push the submit button nothing happens.

Comment: try adding "/" to the form action.. Try restarting the server too /rebuild.

Comment: @CharisAlex please post error or exception that you getting

Comment: nothing strange here you just need to call localhost:port/index.html or .jsp

Comment: @AhmadAl-Kurdi I already did that.

Comment: @DeedarAliBrohi That's the most frustrating part. I get no error from the server. It's just unresponsive i push the button and nothing happens.

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Did that still nothing. Just no response, from the server when i use the submit button of the form.

Comment: @CharisAlex if the page doesn't change at all when you click the submit button, then the form is not being submitted. You can check the network panel to see if anything is being submitted. If nothing is being submitted, you are either not using a submit button or have some javascript somewhere preventing it from being submitted.

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Actually it's a piece of JavaScript code with a switch case for some forms in a login modal that bugged the form. It has a $("form").submit(function () and a deault case where it returns false. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

@CharisAlex here is the problem in your jsp page `<button>` tag doesn't submit form action so you have to modify your code

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Search</button>`
```

replace into

```
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg' value="Search" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it was actually a segment of JavaScript code that prevented the posting of the form.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

instead of using

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Search </button>
```

Comment: Use what instead of what? Please be more specific!

Comment: use input tag  with type submit to create button

Comment: sorry m new to this stack overflow so  i didn't know how to enter html tags  in this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it was actually a segment of JavaScript code that prevented the posting of the form.